# Jquery .AJAX doesn't works on click event

Tags: ajax, jsp, jquery, servlets

I'm going to implement the following:

When user presses button AJAX query is performed to servlet. Depending on the request from server, I change label text.

web.xml

```
 <servlet>
        <servlet-name>RemindPassword</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>app.RemindPassword</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>RemindPassword</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/RemindPassword</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

html code of button

```
 <form>
   <div class="field">
      <label for="email">Your e-mail:</label>
      <input name="email" type="text" class="t">
   </div>
   <input id ="btn" type="submit" value="Send" />
 </form>
```

JS

```
   <script type="text/javascript"> 
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('#btn').click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "/RemindPassword",
            //dataType:text,
            //data: $("#registerSubmit").serialize(),
            success: function(msg){
               $('input[type="submit"]').after("<label for='submit'>" + msg+" " +"</label>");
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
               $('input[type="submit"]').after("<label for='submit'>" + fail+" " +"</label>");
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Probably useful information:

I perform AJAX query from `domain/someJSP/RemindPassword`.
I put servlet in the root of my web app and intentionally put slash before URL in AJAX call. No success. 
 When I used `.get` JQUERY function it worked when I call it on render bit didn't work when I put ajax call `onclick`. `.ajax` didn't work in both cases.

Comment: Where is `.click` event handler?

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry I posted old version. See update.

Comment: What is the error you get ?

Comment: Just not the good selector ? $('#btn').click(function() { ... }

Comment: @Michael, I got nothing. Nor success, nor error. But I saw strange thing - after button click browser redirects me again to `domain/someJSP`. I expect adding slash in ajax URL will send me to `domain/RemindPassword` but no success. It seems, problem in mapping but I can't find it.

Comment: @Vincent LITUR, I added # but it didn't help(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change ID selector, add prevent default and better handle the form submit instead of button click

```
  $('#form1').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault()
```

- assuming that form tag will have ID=form1

Comment: Oh, it worked! e.preventedDefault() - this done the job. I will accept answer after 4 minutes, thanks! Could you explain me, what does `preventdefault` mean?

Comment: to prevent the default action of the button. 
I've updated code to trigger on form submit instead of button click because user can trigger form submit without clicking the button but by pressing enter in textbox